# What are the origins of Ronan the Accuser?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

What is the origin of Ronan the Accuser? I am not familiar with the comics but loved the Guardians of the Galaxy movie.

Comment: Is there anyway I could improve my answer?

Answer (score 14):

I'm not entirely clear which origin you want. Here are links to a few:

- [Origin in the comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronan_the_Accuser#Fictional_character_biography):

  > Ronan was born on the planet Hala, the capital of the Kree Empire in the Greater Magellanic Cloud. Ronan is a member of the alien Kree race and a member of the Accuser Corps, who are the Kree equivalent of military governors and jurists. His rise through the ranks was extraordinary, and he eventually became the third-most powerful being in the Kree Empire. The Supreme Intelligence appointed him "Supreme Accuser of the Kree Empire", and in this role he is known simply as "Ronan the Accuser".
- [Real life origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronan_the_Accuser#Publication_history):

  > Ronan was created by Stan Lee and Jack Kirby in 1967. He first appeared in Fantastic Four vol 1 #65.
- [Origin in the film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronan_the_Accuser#Film):

  > Lee Pace portrays Ronan in the 2014 film Guardians of the Galaxy. Depicted as a Kree fanatic, Ronan refuses to heed the Kree Empire's recent peace treaty with the Nova Empire of Xandar and embarks on a genocidal campaign against the Xandarians.

For more information, see [here](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Ronan_(Earth-616)).